# Keys of a nested "typed" object in typescript

Tags: typescript

Given the following construct:

```
type MyStruckt =  { hello: string; nested: any }

const MY_OBJ: MyStruct = {
  hello: "Hello",
  nested: {
    world: "World",
  },
};
```

How do I get the keys of `nested`?

```
type X = typeof MY_OBJ["nested"];
type NestedKeys = keyof typeof MY_OBJ["nested"];
```

Does not do the trick (as `nested` is any). :(

What I want to write is a hook-like function :

```js
function useMyStruct(obj:MyStruct) {
   type Key = keyof typeof obj["nested"] 
   return function print(key:Key) {
      console.log(obj.nested[key])
   }
}

const printer = useMyStruct(MY_OBJ)
printer("world") // should be OK
printer("something") // should be an error
```

[Here is a playground][1]

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=32&ssc=43&pln=22&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDKwBOBXAxsKBeKUDeUAFhADYkD2AXFAM7ICWAdgOYDcUjEdEAJtQIaMQUAL4AoMWnKM6sAJoB9APIAhAFLU4iVBmz4xuYmSpQARAAlSFUwBoDHLsF7U893AHdySEnzMB1Lx9bexE7EVYJMQB6KKhzcncoHnIoAEkoZghMYGIoAGsIEBoocgAzKAADTm4eCoB+SNBIKAANPSaIMvlldQBtU2qnHlMAXQiOqAA5R14AaULinAKQLo6umEVVNX7B3lGIiRioABFyLg5yTGSoHOgGNDyoAAp+YqqZ2qh6YsEQAEoAHRQShPaKxMFQPyEfiYdLuQTZFLuJD0JxfH5EcjkPIAWhI9AKUFKKEYGHo0mBkWJpOA5MYUBQNAgWmQ6GAT3IACMAFaUFk6YB-fS4G7gaDzYRLQqrMVdLncnYfUZQNxILIoJD06lkilgFGMdnLSgSoWuEUiqQycgkCAAijMDk8gG7Hi9ZYjP5ucTiSTSWR6phOJB6RnMhCsjBPDY9NSegMGiBIJ6mTzeYZCo40QjkFA+KCc6BKWZieNB5M0cgAWyyhCYzFMGdiWZzeYLUEEUETSC8QA

Comment: Well, if nested is `any`, then it's keys are every possible key, ie `string | number | symbol`. Do you know anything more about the type, so you can avoid using `any`?

Comment: I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71159257/157247) based on your edit to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re your edit:

> What I want to write is a hook-like function :
>
> ```
> function useMyStruct(obj:MyStruct) {
>    type Key = keyof typeof obj["nested"] 
>    return function print(key:Key) {
>       console.log(obj.nested[key])
>    }
> }
>
> const printer = useMyStruct(MY_OBJ)
> printer("world") // should be OK
> printer("something") // should be an error
> ```

You can do that using a generic type parameter to your function:

```typescript
function useMyStruct<ObjectType extends MyStruct>(obj: ObjectType) {
    type Key = keyof typeof obj["nested"];
    return function print(key: Key) {
        console.log(obj.nested[key]);
    };
}

const printer = useMyStruct(MY_OBJ);
printer("world");       // works
printer("something");   // error as desired
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDKwBOBXAxsKBeKUDeUAFhADYkD2AXFAM7ICWAdgOYDcUjEdEAJtQIaMQ7AL6sAUOLTlGdWAE0A+gHkAQgCls+cblzEyVKACIAEqQpGANDt2dufbbqdQA7uSQkHRgOrvPVm1wRazFJADMURgx6GSgUGgg4RFQMAB5lACMAKwgMABVwaAgAD2AIRh4aWARkdGAAPgAKcmzqTJz8woBKR11QSCgAaQgQLQBrEfIwqH6IKagWrIBtIzsyniMAXQknJAhgFCRGKAio4BjjsCQmYEaJkGphkB68QOdpWXISCAA6CmZmtkfmteEt7psujtdKERJIPnIrjcIEgtPFEjUUrcYEo1OpIeJEYwykhGkY3B4NpDnLgAPQ01zuMY0AnXInI0k0cgAW32hCYzCMVNp9ORSHcUH4VR4XHoex44iAA)

---

Pre-edit answer (perhaps still relevant to cases where generics wouldn't apply):

> Does not do the trick (as `nested` is `any`). :(

That's because the type of `nested` **is** `any`, because you've said `MY_OBJ` is a `MyStruckt`. So although the runtime value of `nested` is an object with a property called `world`, the compile-time type of `nested` is `any`, because that's what you've expressly told the compiler it is.

If you *don't* tell the compiler that `MY_OBJ` is of type `MyStruckt`, `MY_OBJ` is still assignment-compatible with `MyStruckt` but you can get the keys of the `nested` object:

```typescript
type MyStruckt =  { hello: string; nested: any }

const MY_OBJ = {
  hello: "Hello",
  nested: {
    world: "World",
  },
};

type X = typeof MY_OBJ["nested"];
type NestedKeys = keyof typeof MY_OBJ["nested"]; // "world"
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDKwBOBXAxga2FAvFKA3lABYQA2ZA9gFxQDOyAlgHYDmA3FMxAxACa0AhsxBQAvgCgJaSswawAmgH0A8gCEAUrkIT8pCjSgAiABLkqRgDS6uPYP1oEb+AO6UkZAcYDq7z1ZsxazF2KVBIKAANbXCISgAzRVVNAG0jbl4+IwBdUNioADk7fgBpCBA6bQxyhKhY2phldQ00jPss3KgAei7jNw8soA)

That only works if `MY_OBJ` is declared literally in the code, as it is in your example. If it isn't (if you receive it as a `MyStruckt` parameter or similar), the only compile-time type information you can get for `nested` is `any` (from `MyStruckt`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a transitional object, optionally typed as const depending on your needs

```
type MyStruckt =  { hello: string; nested: any }

const obj0 = {
  hello: "Hello",
  nested: {
    world: "World",
  },
} as const;
const obj1: MyStruckt = obj0;
type X = typeof obj0['nested']
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDKwBOBXAxga2FAvFKA3lABYQA2ZA9gFxQDOyAlgHYDmA3FMxAxACa0AhsxBQAvgCgJaSswZRKAIwBWABlyEJ+UhRpQARAAlyVfQBotXHsH60Cl-AHdKSMgIMB1F2-OWxFsShBOigZOWB2aVl5JWUARlo4RFRMbDxY1UjQSCgADQ1siEoAMwUVVQBtAHJuXj4qgF0gA)

Comment: Doesn't even have to be `as const`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this works:

```js
type MyStruct =  { hello: string; nested: any }

// This function ensures that the obj is of type MyStruct,
// but does not alter the type of the obj
function makeStruct<T extends MyStruct>(obj:T) {
  return obj
}

const MY_OBJ = makeStruct({
  hello: "Hello",
  nested: {
    world: "World",
  },
})

function useMyStruct<T extends MyStruct>(obj:T) {
   type Key = keyof typeof obj["nested"] 
   return function print(key:Key) {
      console.log(obj.nested[key])
   }
}

const printer = useMyStruct(MY_OBJ)
printer("world") // should be OK
printer("something") // should be an error
```

Comment: You don't really need the `makeStruct` function, but it does make errors fairly proactive when you're creating `MY_OBJ` if you don't include the necessary properties for `MyStruct`. That said, that kind of issue shows up immediately when you try to use the hook anyway ([example](https://tsplay.dev/NDPQzN)), all the function does is flag it up *slightly* sooner...